# Spring Boot : Getting Null inputs from Form(reactjs) Submission

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a basic form submission spring boot application. My problem is when I am submitting the form I am getting null results.

Here is my form code :

- **Topic Control.java**

```
package io.group.artifact.MainApplication.TopicController;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
public class TopicControl {
    @Autowired
    private TopicService topicService;

    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public List<Topic> getTopic(){

        return topicService.getAllTopics();


    }
    @RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id) {
    return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, value = "/topics")
    public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic){
        topicService.addTopic(topic);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/topics/{id}")
    public void updateTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic, @PathVariable String id){
        topicService.updateTopic(id, topic);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/topics/{id}")
    public void deleteTopic(@PathVariable String id){
        topicService.deleteTopic(id);
    }
}
```

This code is my react part:

- **CreateEmployeeComponent.jsx**

```
    saveEmployee = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let employee = {firstName: this.state.firstName, iD: this.state.iD, desc: this.state.desc};
        console.log('employee => ' + JSON.stringify(employee));

        EmployeeService.createEmployee(employee).then(res =>{
            this.props.history.push('/topics');
        
        });

    }
```

This also is the front end code

- **EmployeeService.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/topics";

class EmployeeService {

    getEmployees(){
        return axios.get(EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL);
    }

    createEmployee(employee){
        return axios.post(EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL, employee);
    }

}

export default new EmployeeService()
```

In http://localhost:8080/topics I am getting the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By seeing this code, the parameters from the front-end and fields in Request body DTO are different which is wrong as both should match then only it will work.

Front-end :

firstName,iD,desc

Backend :

name,id, description

Ensure these are same in both sides.

Comment: I've made them same on both sides, but still, the error persists.

Comment: Can you check if I've implemented "Axios" correctly?